# Hive JDBC connection in JAVA

Tags: java, jdbc, hive

Error :

> Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not
>   create http connection to
>   jdbc:hive2://xxxxxxxxxx.azurehdinsight.net:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=true;httpPath=/hive2.
>   HTTP Response code: 403

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://xxxxx.azurehdinsight.net:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=true;httpPath=/hive2", "xxx", "xxx");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
...
}
```

My Hive version: 1.2.1.2.5

My pom file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <classifier>standalone</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: check your clusterUser access rights

Answer (score 0):

Check [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) form more details:

> HTTP 403 is returned when the client is not permitted access to the
>   resource for some reason besides authentication

Check your certificate (in case if it is expired etc.), and check if your user has proper rights for accessing Hive.